# Scanner reading as string when used in a different method

Tags: java, string, methods

I have a class project where I need to create a program that requires user input, I want to create a method that gets user input and returns the value to main, for some reason I get the following error when I use the code below,

Names.java:40: error: incompatible types
         userInput = kb.next();
                            ^
  required: int
  found:    String

```
   public static void main(String[] arg)  
               throws FileNotFoundException{  
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);  
      Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));  
      System.out.println("This program allows you to search through the");  
      System.out.println("data from the Social Security Administration");  
      System.out.println("name popularity since 1900.");  
      int userInput;  
      do{  
         userInput = getInput(kb);  
         if(userInput == 1)  
            namePopularity();  
         if(userInput == 2)  
            nameCompare();  
         if(userInput == 3)  
            nameRank();  
      }while(userInput == 4);  
   }  

   //Gets the user input  
   public static int getInput(Scanner kb){  
      int userInput;  
      do{  
         System.out.println("Choose a task number from the following:");  
         System.out.println("1-See histogram of a name's popularity");  
         System.out.println("2-Compare two names in a specific decade");  
         System.out.println("3-Show what name had a specific rank for a certain decade");  
         System.out.println("4-Exit Program");  
         userInput = kb.next();  
         }while(!userInput.hasNextInt());  
      return userInput;  
   }
```

I tried breaking it down to a simpler version, below, but i keep getting that error message, i don't know why its reading it as string rather than a scanner, can somebody help me, it works until i try to use the scanner in a different method.

```
   public static void main(String[] arg)  
            throws FileNotFoundException{  
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);  
      Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));  
      int userInput;  

      System.out.println(getInput(kb));  
   }  
   public static int getInput(Scanner kb){  
      int userInput;  
      System.out.println("write something");  
         userInput = kb.next();  
      return userInput;  
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) for`Scanner`the `next()`method of Scanner returns a String. You want to use `nextInt()`if you want to read an int. An alternative would be to read a String then use Integer.parseInt() and some error checking.